# Can I build my project with oauth2 in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth2orize

I want to use oauth2 authorization and resource servers with nodejs in my project. But I could not that. I tried many times to build oauth2 server with **oauth2orize, express-oauth-server, oauth2-server** libs but does not work. Please help me to build my proejct with oauth2

Comment: Your question basically says "I tried something, and it did not work". You have to be a lot more explicit about **what exactly** you tried **and in what way** it did not give the desired result.

Comment: I used express-oauth-server

Comment: I need to build oauth2 server with resource owner credentials grant

Comment: Seriously, show some code and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

see my blog at http://authguidance.com

NodeJS + tutorial based - with code samples and write ups

And you can send me questions

Very detailed though - might make your brain hurt!!

Comment: Thank you . I will send you some questions

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use passportjs to provide you the oauth 2.0 support. You will need googleClientID and googleClientSecret. Which you can get by registering your application to google developers site

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const keys = require('./keys');
 const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = function(passport){
  passport.use(
new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID:keys.googleClientID,
  clientSecret:keys.googleClientSecret,
  callbackURL:'/auth/google/callback',
  proxy:true
},(accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done)=>{
//     console.log(accessToken);
//     console.log(profile);
  const image = profile.photos[0].value.substring(0,profile.photos[0].value.indexOf('?'));

  const newUser = {
    googleID:profile.id,
    firstName:profile.name.givenName,
    lastName :profile.name.familyName,
    email:profile.emails[0].value,
    image:image
  }

  //Check for existing user
  User.findOne({
    googleID:profile.id
  }).then(user=>{
    if(user){
      //Return user
      done(null,user);
    }
    else{
      //Create a new user
      new User(newUser)
      .save()
      .then(user=> done(null,user)); 
    }
  })
 })
)

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
 User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
   done(err, user);
     });
   });
 }
```

> Dependencies  = "passport": "^0.4.0",
>       "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0"

```
This will redirect req. to above code..
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

 router.get('/google',passport.authenticate('google',{scope:
      ['profile','email']}));

 router.get('/google/callback', 
   passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
   function(req, res) {
   // Successful authentication, redirect home.
   res.redirect('/dashboard');
  });

   router.get('/verify',(req,res)=>{
   if(req.user){
   console.log(req.user);
  }else{
   console.log('Not Auth');
  }
});

router.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
   req.logout();
   res.redirect('/');
 })
 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank you for your hepl. But I need to build my custom own oauth2-server provider . Such as oauth2-server nmp lib or express-oauth-server npm lib

Comment: Can I use Passport JS's **passport-oauth2-resource-owner-password** npm lib . Who has an example that